# Box2d How to move body to position like CCMoveTo

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, move

Hi you there how to move body to exact position like CCMoveTo action in cocos2d. i figure out how to make this with SetLinearVelocity

```
b2Vec2 force = (t * endPosition) - body->GetLinearVelocity();
        [self runAction: [CCSequence actions: [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
                                                                                body->SetLinearVelocity( force );
                                                                           }],
                                              [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration: (1.0f / t)],
                                              [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
                                                                                body->SetLinearVelocity( b2Vec2_zero );
                                                                            }],nil]];
```

i found on forum this code but it doesn't help me..

```
b2Vec2 currentPosition = body->GetPosition();
b2Vec2 desiredPosition = ...;
b2Vec2 necessaryMovement = desiredPosition - currentPosition;
float necessaryDistance = necessaryMovement.Length();
necessaryMovement.Normalize();
float forceMagnitude = b2Min(maxAllowableForce, necessaryDistance);
b2Vec2 force = forceMagnitude * necessaryMovement;
body->ApplyForce( force, body->GetWorldCenter() );
```

same problem can't stop body at target point.. so please help me.

Answer (score 1):

you have to run the code you have found in update call.
every update you move your object a little bit towards to your "desiredPosition"

```
float pForce = 10;

b2Vec2 forceDir = b2Vec2( ( desiredPosition.x - body->GetPosition().x ) * pForce  , 
         ( desiredPosition.y - body->GetPosition().y ) * pForce );
```

apply foreDir to your body and play with pForce

Comment: thanks you for answer, i try with timer but still without success still can't hold body on desired position. it can only happen when body move slowly otherwise body fly away about 3-5 or even more pixels. i want to stop body exact desired position.

Comment: check my edit, and keep the update function running all the time. dont  stop it even if your body is on your desired position

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that if you need to move, for example, rockets or something like that toward a target then it's better if you use a KinematicBody and the set the linear velocity of the body at each frame.

The formula given by Chakalaka works fine if you see the Vector2 as the linear velocity of the body you want to move.